# Simple C++ syntax question about colon

Tags: c++, syntax

I just saw a code snippet with a piece of syntax that I have never seen before.
What does `bool start : 1;` mean? I found it inside a class definition in a header file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
struct record {
    char *name;
    int refcount : 4;
    unsigned dirty : 1;
};
```

Those are bit-fields; the number gives the exact size of the field, in bits. (See any complete book on C for the details.) Bit-fields can be used to save space in structures having several binary flags or other small fields, and they can also be used in an attempt to conform to externally-imposed storage layouts. (Their success at the latter task is mitigated by the fact that bit-fields are assigned left-to-right on some machines and right-to-left on others).

Note that the colon notation for specifying the size of a field in bits is only valid in structures (and in unions); you cannot use this mechanism to specify the size of arbitrary variables.

- References: K&R1 Sec. 6.7 pp. 136-8
- K&R2 Sec. 6.9 pp. 149-50
- ISO Sec. 6.5.2.1
- H&S Sec. 5.6.5 pp. 136-8

Answer (score 5):

It means that `start` is 1 bit wide, as opposed to the normal `bool` which is 1 byte long. You can pack multiple smaller variables into a larger variable and the compiler will generate all the and/or code necessary to read/write it for you. You will take a (noticeable) performance hit, but, if used right, you'll use a lot less memory.

Comment: Performance of what? I assume the compiling process is slowed down (which shouldn;t be a problem imho), but is the runtime performance slowed down as well?

Comment: Yes, at runtime every access you make to this variables (either read or write) have to be translated to bit-level accesses. For example if you read one of these things, you first have to load the big field in a register, AND it with a mask and then shift right, which is at least 3 times slower than a normal read. Same goes for the write.

Comment: It gets even worse with cross-boundary bit fields, they have to be combined, doubling the amount of work (if they aren't just outright ignored).

Answer (score 4):

it's a bitfield. : 1 means one bit is used.
see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe(VS.71).aspx

Comment: URL doesn't seem to be valid anymore.

Answer (score 4):

See the Wikipedia entry about [Bit Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Bit_fields). It tells the compiler how many bits the structure member should occupy.

Answer (score 3):

It makes the member `start` into a bit-field, with 1 bit of space reserved.

It's only valid for struct/class members, you can't have a bit-field variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for [bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Essentially, you define a field in a struct to have only a few bits of a full byte or short or int.
Several bit fields may share the same int so this method can be used as a clever way to avoid some bit manipulations in constructing values.

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for describing *[bit fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28VS.71%29.aspx)*. This is a way of packing more information into a smaller amount of storage. Whereas normally a bool would take at least a byte (probably more) to represent, by using bit fields, you can combine several bools into one byte with a simple syntax.

Be careful though. As one of lesser-known areas of the language, you may run into corner cases when using them. For example, the data structures thus produced are probably not portable between processor types.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bit-field](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7l.doc/language/ref/clrc03defbitf.htm). But I've never tried making bit-fields on boolean.